# How to present another view controller under tab bar on button press inside a tab bar controller view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4.2

I have 4 tabs and in the home tab, I have a button to goto profile view controller.

When I use segue, The view changes completely and it's presented over tab bar. So it gets hidden.

I want to present it under the tab bar so that I can quickly navigate to other tabs without a back button.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: what should i explain more...i have explained more than enough

Comment: wanna more clarification.

Comment: Add the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: try NavigationController & pushViewController code for redirection

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right way or not. but you can add presenting `viewcontroller`'s view as `subview` with the same animation.